# Facets & multi-valued, numeric fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I use an elasticsearch facet (or aggregate) to get e.g. the average of the maximum value in each document, rather than the average of all values across all documents?

Answer (score 1):

While you can use a `script_field` for this, I'd recommend determining the maximum at index time and then storing it in a separate field to facet/aggregate on. It'll be faster, and the memory requirement for doing the facet will be much smaller.